# How to set empty string nested array in project of mongodb

Tags: mongodb

How to set priceId value empty string if have null value in options array during of project in MongoDB.
If have a collection of levels. A sample document looks like below:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d9d6670eef623212fc71347"),
    "id" : 1,
    "name" : "option 1",
    "optionLevel" : [
        {
            "id" : 1,
            "deparmentId" : null,
            "options" : [
                {
                    "id" : 1,
                    "name" : "option 1",
                    "priceId" : null
                },
                {
                    "id" : 2,
                    "name" : "option 2",
                    "priceId" : null
                }
            ],
            "name" : "level 1"
        },
        {
            "id" : 2,
            "deparmentId" : null,
            "name" : "level 2",
            "options" : [
                {
                    "id" : 3,
                    "name" : "option 3",
                    "priceId" : null
                },
                {
                    "id" : 4,
                    "name" : "option 4",
                    "priceId" : null
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**How can I project a `priceId` inside `options` as empty string if its null?**

Answer (score 2):

We can use **[$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/)** to reformat the structure of an array.

**The following query can get us the expected output:**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields:{
            "optionLevel":{
                $map:{
                    "input":"$optionLevel",
                    "as":"doc",
                    "in":{
                        $mergeObjects:[
                            "$$doc",
                            {
                                "options":{
                                    $map:{
                                        "input":"$$doc.options",
                                        "as":"option",
                                        "in":{
                                            $mergeObjects:[
                                                "$$option",
                                                {
                                                    "priceId":{
                                                        $ifNull:["$$option.priceId",""]
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
]).pretty()
```

**Data set:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d9d6670eef623212fc71347"),
    "id" : 1,
    "name" : "option 1",
    "optionLevel" : [
        {
            "id" : 1,
            "deparmentId" : null,
            "options" : [
                {
                    "id" : 1,
                    "name" : "option 1",
                    "priceId" : null
                },
                {
                    "id" : 2,
                    "name" : "option 2",
                    "priceId" : null
                }
            ],
            "name" : "level 1"
        },
        {
            "id" : 2,
            "deparmentId" : null,
            "name" : "level 2",
            "options" : [
                {
                    "id" : 3,
                    "name" : "option 3",
                    "priceId" : null
                },
                {
                    "id" : 4,
                    "name" : "option 4",
                    "priceId" : null
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**Output:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d9d6670eef623212fc71347"),
    "id" : 1,
    "name" : "option 1",
    "optionLevel" : [
        {
            "id" : 1,
            "deparmentId" : null,
            "options" : [
                {
                    "id" : 1,
                    "name" : "option 1",
                    "priceId" : ""
                },
                {
                    "id" : 2,
                    "name" : "option 2",
                    "priceId" : ""
                }
            ],
            "name" : "level 1"
        },
        {
            "id" : 2,
            "deparmentId" : null,
            "name" : "level 2",
            "options" : [
                {
                    "id" : 3,
                    "name" : "option 3",
                    "priceId" : ""
                },
                {
                    "id" : 4,
                    "name" : "option 4",
                    "priceId" : ""
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```